# Add pagination for shop page on woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, woocommerce, shortcode

I am using this shortcode for woocommerce shop page to display products:

```
[recent_products per_page="100" columns="4"]
```

This shortcode display all 100 products in single page. How to do pagination for this page?

and my arg is:

```
array(
     'per_page' => '100',
      'columns' => '4',
      'orderby' => 'date',
      'order' => 'desc'
)
```

Comment: This is my quest, :(. I have researched it 2 days...

Comment: refer this link and go through the 5th comment ,, [https://wordpress.org/support/topic/pagination-not-working-50]